# Using on() or once() for `open` event in MongooseJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I've seen a bunch of different ways of actually setting up a MongoDB connection:

1. I've seen some code where people don't use the `open` or `error` event
2. `mongoose.connection.on('open', callback());`
3. `mongoose.connection.once('open', callback());`

My take on it is:

- If my app only connected to the database when it needs to use it, use (2)
- If my app is constantly connected to the database ... it doesn't matter if I use (2) or (3)?

Which also raises the question, should my app maintain a persistent connection to the database (server and database running on same machine)?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that it doesn't matter if you use (2) or (3) when your application is constantly connected to the database.

As far as a persistent connection goes, the only cost of that is a tcp keepalive packet every once in a while. It's up to you to determine if the extra socket is worth not having to make a new connection for every call.